# Mongodb community operator kubernetes with aws eks and efs as storage

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, amazon-eks, amazon-efs

I am implementing mongodb stateful using it's community operator on AWS EKS, and for persistent storage I am using EFS.

below is my yaml file, where I have mentioned my custom pvc, which is an efs.

```
---
apiVersion: mongodbcommunity.mongodb.com/v1
kind: MongoDBCommunity
metadata:
  name: example-mongodb
spec:

  statefulSet:
    spec:
      volumeClaimTemplates:
        - metadata:
            name: data-volume
          spec:
            storageClassName: efs-sc
  members: 2
  type: ReplicaSet
  version: "6.0.5"
  security:
    authentication:
      modes: ["SCRAM"]
  users:

    - name: my-user
      db: admin
      passwordSecretRef: # a reference to the secret that will be used to generate the user's password
        name: my-user-password
      roles:
        - name: clusterAdmin
          db: admin
        - name: userAdminAnyDatabase
          db: admin
        - name: readWrite
          db: admin



      scramCredentialsSecretName: my-scram
  additionalMongodConfig:
    storage.wiredTiger.engineConfig.journalCompressor: zlib
```

now when I am implementing it, it is creating required pv and pvc dynamically, and I can see that it is writing somoe file in the efs too, below is snapshot for the same.

[image]

but the pod is getting into crashloopbackoff, I am putting the logs of the pod below.

```
{"t":{"$date":"2024-01-11T08:55:38.344+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"6.0.5","gitVersion":"c9a99c120371d4d4c52cbb15dac34a36ce8d3b1d","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"ubuntu2204","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-01-11T08:55:38.344+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Ubuntu","version":"22.04"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-01-11T08:55:38.344+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"config":"/data/automation-mongod.conf","net":{"bindIp":"0.0.0.0","port":27017},"replication":{"replSetName":"example-mongodb"},"security":{"authorization":"enabled","keyFile":"/var/lib/mongodb-mms-automation/authentication/keyfile"},"setParameter":{"authenticationMechanisms":"SCRAM-SHA-256"},"storage":{"dbPath":"/data"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-01-11T08:55:38.385+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22315,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Opening WiredTiger","attr":{"config":"create,cache_size=256M,session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,remove=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),builtin_extension_config=(zstd=(compression_level=6)),file_manager=(close_idle_time=600,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=2000),statistics_log=(wait=0),json_output=(error,message),verbose=[recovery_progress:1,checkpoint_progress:1,compact_progress:1,backup:0,checkpoint:0,compact:0,evict:0,history_store:0,recovery:0,rts:0,salvage:0,tiered:0,timestamp:0,transaction:0,verify:0,log:0],"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-01-11T08:55:39.170+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"WT",       "id":22435,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger error message","attr":{"error":1,"message":{"ts_sec":1704963339,"ts_usec":170490,"thread":"1:0x7fb648844cc0","session_name":"connection","category":"WT_VERB_DEFAULT","category_id":9,"verbose_level":"ERROR","verbose_level_id":-3,"msg":"__posix_open_file:812:/data/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open","error_str":"Operation not permitted","error_code":1}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-01-11T08:55:39.238+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"WT",       "id":22435,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger error message","attr":{"error":17,"message":{"ts_sec":1704963339,"ts_usec":238564,"thread":"1:0x7fb648844cc0","session_name":"connection","category":"WT_VERB_DEFAULT","category_id":9,"verbose_level":"ERROR","verbose_level_id":-3,"msg":"__posix_open_file:812:/data/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open","error_str":"File exists","error_code":17}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-01-11T08:55:39.248+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"WT",       "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":{"ts_sec":1704963339,"ts_usec":248704,"thread":"1:0x7fb648844cc0","session_name":"connection","category":"WT_VERB_BLOCK","category_id":3,"verbose_level":"NOTICE","verbose_level_id":-1,"msg":"unexpected file WiredTiger.wt found, renamed to WiredTiger.wt.1"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-01-11T08:55:39.258+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"WT",       "id":22435,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger error message","attr":{"error":1,"message":{"ts_sec":1704963339,"ts_usec":258672,"thread":"1:0x7fb648844cc0","session_name":"connection","category":"WT_VERB_DEFAULT","category_id":9,"verbose_level":"ERROR","verbose_level_id":-3,"msg":"__posix_open_file:812:/data/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open","error_str":"Operation not permitted","error_code":1}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-01-11T08:55:39.318+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"WT",       "id":22435,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger error message","attr":{"error":17,"message":{"ts_sec":1704963339,"ts_usec":318557,"thread":"1:0x7fb648844cc0","session_name":"connection","category":"WT_VERB_DEFAULT","category_id":9,"verbose_level":"ERROR","verbose_level_id":-3,"msg":"__posix_open_file:812:/data/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open","error_str":"File exists","error_code":17}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-01-11T08:55:39.329+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"WT",       "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":{"ts_sec":1704963339,"ts_usec":329772,"thread":"1:0x7fb648844cc0","session_name":"connection","category":"WT_VERB_BLOCK","category_id":3,"verbose_level":"NOTICE","verbose_level_id":-1,"msg":"unexpected file WiredTiger.wt found, renamed to WiredTiger.wt.2"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-01-11T08:55:39.339+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"WT",       "id":22435,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger error message","attr":{"error":1,"message":{"ts_sec":1704963339,"ts_usec":339405,"thread":"1:0x7fb648844cc0","session_name":"connection","category":"WT_VERB_DEFAULT","category_id":9,"verbose_level":"ERROR","verbose_level_id":-3,"msg":"__posix_open_file:812:/data/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open","error_str":"Operation not permitted","error_code":1}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-01-11T08:55:39.350+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22347,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to start up WiredTiger under any compatibility version. This may be due to an unsupported upgrade or downgrade."}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-01-11T08:55:39.350+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":28595,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Terminating.","attr":{"reason":"1: Operation not permitted"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-01-11T08:55:39.350+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"ASSERT",   "id":23091,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":28595,"file":"src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp","line":708}}
{"t":{"$date":"2024-01-11T08:55:39.350+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"ASSERT",   "id":23092,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}
```

When I am doing same without specifying my custom pvc (in that case it is using ebs of the nodegroup) it is working fine but when I am using my custom pvc it is throwing me that error.

Thanks for considering.

Comment: I am also facing exactly the same issue. After deleting everything from the /data directory by attaching to mongdb-agent container, the mongod container stopped restarting. But it is stuck at waiting for something. Found the following in the log,

2024-01-16T19:34:25.678Z INFO versionhook/main.go:32 Running version change post-start hook
2024-01-16T19:34:25.679Z INFO versionhook/main.go:39 Waiting for agent health status...
2024-01-16T19:34:26.680Z INFO versionhook/main.go:75 Pod should not be deleted, mongod started

Answer (score 0):

The EFS volumes mounted in the Mongod container appear to lack the correct file system permissions. The issue was resolved by aligning the `uid` and `gid` parameters with the security context in the StatefulSet and adjusting the directory permissions on the EFS storage claim.

A similar issue was reported which helped to figure the issue.
https://github.com/bitnami/charts/issues/8350

Security context in StatefulSet:

```yaml
securityContext:
  fsGroup: 1001
  runAsGroup: 1001
  runAsUser: 1001
```

Full MongoDBCommunity resource with the above security context applied:

```yaml
apiVersion: mongodbcommunity.mongodb.com/v1
kind: MongoDBCommunity
metadata:
  name: mongo
spec:
  members: 2
  type: ReplicaSet
  version: "6.0.5"
  security:
    authentication:
      modes: ["SCRAM"]
  
  users:
    - name: my-user
      db: admin
      passwordSecretRef: # a reference to the secret that will be used to generate the user's password
        name: my-user-password
      roles:
        - name: root
          db: admin
        - name: clusterAdmin
          db: admin
        - name: userAdminAnyDatabase
          db: admin
      scramCredentialsSecretName: my-scram
  additionalMongodConfig:
    storage.wiredTiger.engineConfig.journalCompressor: zlib
    storage.wiredTiger.engineConfig.cacheSizeGB: 1
  statefulSet:
    spec:      
      volumeClaimTemplates:
        - metadata:
            name: data-volume
          spec:
            accessModes:
              - ReadWriteOnce
            resources:
              requests:
                storage: 1Gi
        
      template:
        spec:
          securityContext:
            fsGroup: 1001
            runAsGroup: 1001
            runAsUser: 1001
          containers:            
            - name: mongod              
              resources:
                limits:
                  cpu: "3900m"
                  memory: 14Gi
                requests:
                  cpu: 3
                  memory: 12Gi
```

EFS StorageClass:

```yaml
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: efs-sc
  annotations:
    storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: "true"
provisioner: efs.csi.aws.com
parameters:
  provisioningMode: efs-ap
  fileSystemId: fs-xxxxx
  directoryPerms: "777"
  uid: "1001"
  gid: "1001"
  basePath: "/dynamic_provisioning"
```